# Can Hibernate orphanRemoval work with unique constraints?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 entities: `Role` and `Privilege`. One role has many privileges. The entities look like this:

```
@Entity
public class Role {

    private Integer id;
    private String code;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "role", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Privilege> privileges;
}

@Entity
public class Privilege {

    private Integer id;
    private String code;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    private Role role;
}
```

The `privilege` table has the unique constraint `U__ROLE_ID__CODE__PRIVILEGE` on the `role_id` and `code` columns.

I have a REST endpoint which updates roles. The update includes also changing privileges assigned to a role:

```
private static void setPrivileges(Set<Privilege> existing, Set<Privilege> privileges) {
    existing.clear();
    existing.addAll(privileges);
}
```

By some reason, when I do the update of a role, Hibernate first *inserts new privileges into the privilege table*, and only then it *removes the orphaned privileges*. As a result, the update fails with the `U__ROLE_ID__CODE__PRIVILEGE` constraint violation in case when the new list of privileges contains at least one privilege from the old list.

Without the constraint everything works fine. However, removing the constraint does not look like a perfect solution.

Is it possible to change the order the Hibernate handles the role-privilege relationship update so that first the orphaned privileges are removed and only then the new ones are inserted?

The reproduction project is available [here](https://github.com/yaskovdev/sandbox/blob/master/spring-data-sandbox/src/main/java/com/yaskovdev/sandbox/spring/data/RoleServiceImpl.java#L39).

Comment: Have you had solution for this case ?

Comment: @LoiNguyenTri, I ended up changing the `setPrivileges` method: instead of clearing `existing` and then adding `privileges`, I only delete from `existing` the privileges that are not present in `privileges` and then add to `existing` the privileges that are absent in `existing`, but present in `privileges`. I.e., the privileges that are present in both `existing` and `privileges` remain untouched.

Answer (score -1):

```
// You can flush:

private static void setPrivileges(Set<Privilege> existing, Set<Privilege> privileges) {
    existing.clear();
    repository.flush(); // queues delete statements before subsequent operations
    existing.addAll(privileges);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You may want to revisit the `CascadeType`. If you are looking to propagate deletes upon removal of the Role you will want to use `CasadeType.REMOVE`

Because you have it set to `CascadeType.ALL` you'll notice that each update/persistence attempt on `Role` will propagate to the `Privilege`. Thus conflicting with the the unique constraint on these tables.